# Visual Studio 2015 IntelliSense in .cpp files #included as headers

Tags: c++, intellisense, visual-studio-2015

In my project I have a main cpp file and any other files are excluded from the build and I include them from the main cpp file to create one translation unit. This worked perfectly in VS 2013 however I am having issues in 2015 where any cpp files that are not included in the build display types defined in other cpp files with red errors. The project builds fine and I can F12 to the type definitions, but the types do not appear in intellisense and are displayed as errors.

Does anyone know if this is a known issue or can any else replicate it - or is it something specific to my setup?

For example I have main.cpp

```
struct Foo
{
    int Bar;
};

#include "Test.cpp"

int main()
{
    Foo x = Test();

    return 0;
}
```

And Test.cpp which is exclude from the build using VS UI.

```
Foo Test()
{
    Foo x;
    x.Bar = 2;
    return x;
}
```

This builds but intellisense won't display Foo from Test.cpp and will display red errors under Foo.

Comment: I am sorry I missed a semi colon and double quotes. I was in the process of reinstalling VS when I asked this. Although that makes no difference to what I am asking. The updated code snippet works fine in Visual Studio 2013 but I get the described issue in 2015.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can replicate your issue in Visual Studio 2015.

Excluding the files from build isn't going to do what you want here. Since you're effectively using those `.cpp` files as header files, you need to indicate that to IntelliSense.

In the properties of those files, revert the `Excluded From Build` setting to `<inherit from parent or project defaults>` and set `Item Type` to `C/C++ header` (remember to have `All Configurations` and `All Platforms` selected at the top).

At this point, the squiggles are still there. Save and close the solution, and then delete the solution's `.sdf` file (it will be recreated automatically). Reopen the solution and enjoy the lack of squiggles.

Comment: Excellent! That was the issue. I changed the type to be "does not participate in build" rather than c header and it works exactly like it did in 2013! Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have the same issue but for a boost library say scoped_ptr.hpp. I have specified the boost directory in "Include directories" and Intellisense doesn't show any errors at the #include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp> but any use of boost::scoped_ptr itself is accompanied by the intellisense errors. Any idea how that can be resolved?

Comment: Also if I change some property of a project, say "Item Type", where exactly is this change strored? Inside the .vcxproj file or the .sln file or somewhere else?

Comment: I did find that it is the .vcxproj and .vcxproj.filters files that are storing those values.

Comment: @rents I can't replicate that on my side, sorry. The boost source files shouldn't normally be part of your project; you just `#include` them as external files, so they shouldn't appear in the list inside the `.vcxproj`. In my experience, many problems with IntelliSense are resolved by rebuilding the index file as described above. The format has changed in recent versions and the extension is `.VC.db`. I'd clean up the solution's intermediate output files as well for good measure.